# HAProxy: It is possible to balance requests over a persistent connection to different backend servers?

Tags: haproxy

I have the following (partial) Haproxy config:

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:3333
    default_backend servers

backend servers
    balance roundrobin
    server server1 xxxx:1234 check
    server server2 xxxx:4567 check
```

When connecting to haproxy at port 3333 with a persistent connection, all requests over that connection seem to be passed to the same backend server.

I would have thought having a persistent connection to haProxy, would be orthogonal to how requests were balanced over that connection.

Is there a way to balance the requests?

Similarly: I feel I should be able to add:

```
http-reuse always
option http-keep-alive
```

Which would signal for haproxy to keep connections to the backend servers open and that sharing/reusing of these connections between different clients is okay. This should still allow multiple requests on the same *client* connection to be balanced over different backend servers.